# ASUS RT-N56U router Linux create mount point issue

Tags: mkdir

On my RT-N56U router I'm trying to create a ext3 partition on an attached usb drive to store my media center data. The problem is I am unable to create to a mount point after creating the partition. When I run this command: `mkdir /media/AiDisk_a1`, it says it can't do it because file system is read only. This is probably because it's the in memory router OS. How can I mount my ext3 partition to /media/AiDisk_a1?

Also, is there a way in Linux to create a mount point without having write access to the main OS volume?

Comment: Which OS is your router running?

Comment: I believe it's a proprietary port of HyperWRT and Tomato. It's got all of the basic linux tools though fdisk, ftsab, df, mkdir etc. I was trying to follow [this](http://code.google.com/p/rt-n56u/wiki/HowToConfigureOptware) guide but it fails at the mkdir command.

Comment: It should work. The fact that it doesn't only implies disk partitioning and formatting did not complete correctly. Restart from beginning, following the instructions verbatim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try and create /media/AiDisk_a1 directory it won't work. Just build the ext3 partition and reconnect the drive and it will auto-mount it.